# Best Way to Store Autodesk-Forge Refresh Tokens

Tags: php, mysql, database, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

currently I am building a web application using the autodesk-forge viewer and fusion360. My project is similar to [this](https://github.com/adamenagy/models-website) tutorial where I only have to authorize m account once and then users can use refresh tokens to be able to view the models within my account. Currently I am using MySQL to store my refresh token. I currently only have one column and one row within my table and every time a new refresh token is generated, it replaces the old one inside the one row. My code for refreshing the token looks as follows:

```
 $rToken = $_POST['Value'];
  $query = "UPDATE tblMachineViewerToken SET Value='$rToken'";
```

So the one row in the table is updated every time a new refresh token is generated. Is this an adequate way to store the refresh token, as I have had a couple instances where I have had to authorize my account again. Any help is much appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code it is hard to know what the issue could be, but it is very likely that you got either an expired refresh_token or a concurrency issue. Before I jump into answering your questions, let's assume you store the access_token and refresh_token in your database. From a security perspective, it is dangerous to share a token from a single BIM360 user to many of your users. It means that all your users can access your data on your behalf with your privileges without you knowing, and in case something wrong happens, you would never know who did what.

To come back on your issue, let's say that userA and userB access your application at the same time (few milliseconds difference); your application for userA detects that it needs to refresh the access_token, while doing the refresh process; userB access your application as well, and your application also detects the token needs a refresh, because userA refresh tasks hasn't yet completed. In that case and because a refresh_token can be used only once, one of the user refresh tasks will return an empty token, and you would loose the connection. You need to make sure that your code runs as a singleton task, and keeps all other requests waiting for that task to complete.

Another simple reason is that a given refresh_token is only valid 14 days, so you need to make sure to refresh the access_token and refresh_token at least once every 14 days.

Comment: Thanks for the help @cyrille ! That is what is probably going wrong. Any idea on how I can make sure that other requests wait for the first task to be completed before executing?

Comment: @matthew-vidovic - the simplest implementation (working for all languages) is to implement a semaphore.

Comment: If I send and receive the token from javascript, to php and sql, should my semaphore be in php or javascript? @cyrille

Comment: could you please check out my new question @cyrille https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62781249/use-a-semaphore-to-fix-a-concurrency-issue