# Use a Semaphore to fix a Concurrency Issue

Tags: php, sql, semaphore, autodesk-forge

I recently asked a question: link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62775489/best-way-to-store-autodesk-forge-refresh-tokens) regarding the best way to store refresh tokens in my autodesk-forge web application. I am currently storing the refresh token in an SQL database with only one row and column, containing the refresh token. Steps regarding the token are as follows:

1. When a user signs in, a GET method is called to retrieve the latest token from the database. Returndata.php simply connects to the SQL DB and retrieves the row from the table. Get method code:

```
function getRefreshToken() {
    $.get("returndata.php",
        function(response) {
            var res = JSON.parse(response);
           console.log(response);
            console.log(res);
            refreshToken = res[0].Value;
           // console.log(refreshToken);
            useRefresh();
           // console.log(response.value);
            //var times = response.times;
        }, 
    );  
}
```

2. The token is returned and used to get an access token for the user.
3. When the access token is retrieved, it comes with a refresh token, which is subsequently saved in the SQL database in the same row as the previous refresh token. Savesettings.php simply connects to the DB and updates the single row, with the new refresh token. Code for POST method to store refresh token:

```
function saveRefreshToken() {
    
    $.post("savesettings.php",
    {
       Value: refreshToken,
    },
    function(data, status){
    console.log(data);
  });
    
}
```

For the most part, this method works fine, however there have been a couple times where it has bugged out. I believe this is due to a concurrency issue. Where if two users are accessing the DB at very similar times, the data may become corrupted or the wrong data may be given. To fix this, I know I need to use a semaphore so that other requests wait until the first is done before executing. How can I use a semaphore to achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am very stuck on this issue. Thanks. Cheers!!

EDIT

```
function getToken(){
    $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/gettoken',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    data:'client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&grant_type=authorization_code&code=' + code + '&redirect_uri=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    
    success:function(response){
       // console.log(response);
        access_token = response.access_token;
        console.log(access_token);
        console.log(response);
        refreshToken = response.refresh_token;
        saveRefreshToken()
        
    }
})
}

function useRefresh(){
$.ajax({
    method:'POST',
    url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/refreshtoken',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    data:'client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token='+refreshToken+'&scope=data:read',
success:function(response){
    console.log(response);
    refreshToken = response.refresh_token;
    //console.log(refreshToken);
    access_token = response.access_token;
    saveRefreshToken();
}
})
}
```

Comment: Seeing the code above means that you are exposing your token in the browser, right? this is a security leak, and you should not be doing this. The risk is that someone steal your token and if the original scope is too high, you are compromising your data. You may need to refactor your application to secure the tokens. I'll be happy to help you on this.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help again. I currently am doing this, but when the user gets a token using the refresh token, the only scope on it is data:read. However when I'm authorizing, I also have a data:write. If the user can get the data:write token, it would be a security leak. So, how should I handle the token instead @cyrille

Comment: Just adding @cyrille , I am not able to download NPM packages so I am not able to use things like express.js

Comment: I am running my web-app from a LAN and when I try to install NPM packages I get the following message:                                                     \\team\wwwroot'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory. @cyrille I have included my token functions in my post now

Comment: you can contact me at cyrille @ autodesk . com

Comment: okay @cyrille ,  I have emailed you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evert is correct when it is related to MySQL racing issue only. In your case, you are also calling another server to fetch an access token; meaning we need to lock the table for read/write while doing a refresh.

I have written a little example [here](https://github.com/cyrillef/simple-forge-php-sample), which does the minimum things to solve the issue. However, as Evert said, it would only work on a single server to handle HTTP requests if you choose the semaphore approach. If you are doing load balancing, we would need to use the mysql/redis lock approach. I said Redis, because it would be a better choice than mysql on that topic.

The sample will also show you the right way to fetch token(s) in a Forge application. In the code above I noticed you were using $.ajax() code, meaning you were doing HTTP calls on the OAuth server from the HTML page (on the client?) - doing this expose you to high security problem, you are leaking your access tokens, and clientID/secret keys. Anyone can steal your clientID/secret and start using your account without you knowing.

You should be issuing 2 access tokens, one public with minimum privileges (this one will be used for the Viewer only). The second token, with additional privileges, will remain on the server and will never be exposed to any client application.

The example does 2 simple operations:

- Display a model in the viewer using the public token
- List models in your bucket or folder using the internal token

The sample also show a 2 legged flow and a 3 legged code flow. While in theory both should be working the same way, there is an important difference to know.

1. You can generate as many 2 legged token you want, any time. It means that you will always get a valid token, even if you your token multiple times at the same moment. You actually, do not refresh a token, you create a new one each time, and doing that does not invalidate previous generated tokens. The sample is a bit lazy, and just fetch now token whenever it needs without bothering of the HTTP requests handled by the server.
2. While you can generate as many 3 legged token (code flow) you want as well, you would be limited by the fact you need to login each time you create a new one. However, when you create an access token, you get a refresh token coming with it which will let you renew the access_token every-time you need. However, there is 3 caveats on refreshing tokens:

   - a refresh token is valid 14 days only, so you need to refresh the token at least once every 14 days.
   - when you created the token the first time, you need to provide all the scopes you may need. When refreshing a token, you can downgrade scopes, but you will never be able to add new scopes.
   - whenever you are using a refresh token, this one is lost, but you get a new one. This last token is the one you will need to use next.

To use the 2legged version, just got to the root of your server, for example http://localhost/

To use the 3legged version, go to http://localhost/login for creating a new pair of tokens, otherwise go to http://localhost/www/bim360.html

There is also a little test example which will fires 5 HTTP request at the same time on your server. I limited my Apache instance to process 2 requests at a time,  this is to verify that when renewing tokens, all request are not racing each others which will make your token/refresh token out of sync.

The [readme](https://github.com/cyrillef/simple-forge-php-sample/blob/master/README.md) should have enough details to deploy the sample and navigate through the code.

Comment: It all looks ood, but when I try to run I get the following error:

Comment: ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException: Unable to read any of the environment file(s) at [C:\xampp\htdocs\simple-forge-php-sample\server\.env]. in C:\xampp\htdocs\simple-forge-php-sample\vendor\vlucas\phpdotenv\src\Store\FileStore.php on line 57
( ! ) Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException: Unable to read any of the environment file(s) at [C:\xampp\htdocs\simple-forge-php-sample\server\.env]. in C:\xampp\htdocs\simple-forge-php-sample\vendor\vlucas\phpdotenv\src\Store\FileStore.php on line 57        @cyrille

Comment: let's meet and I'll help you to deploy the sample. For the error above, you probably forgot to create a .env file in the server folder.

Comment: when I put the .env file inside the server folder I get the error that no webpage was found with the web adress: http://localhost/simple-forge-php-sample/index.php @cyrille

Comment: I also can't find the files in js and css folders, I get the errors: bim360.html:16 GET http://localhost/www/www/www/js/bim360.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
bim360.html:15 GET http://localhost/www/www/www/css/index.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
bim360.html:16 GET http://localhost/www/www/www/js/bim360.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
bim360.html:15 GET http://localhost/www/www/www/css/index.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) @cyrille

Answer (score 0):

If you're running into concurrency issues with PHP and MySQL, semaphores is not the right level to solve this. What if, for example, you want to run a second server to handle PHP requests.

The correct way to handle this is in your database. If the corruption happens during a single request, maybe your queries are wrong or you need to use transactions or locks.